# How to delete multiple same characters from a file using bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I have this script which removes the first periods from a file in order to unhide it. However, all it can do is remove the first period and not the succeeding periods, which makes the file still hidden. What I want to know now is how I can remove more than 1 periods at a time to unhide the file.

```
#!/bin/bash
period='.'
for i in $@; do
      if [[ "$i" == "$period"* ]] ; then
            mv "$i" "${i#"$period"}"
      else
            mv $i .${i}
      fi
 done
```

I have some knowledge in using grep and regex so I thought of using + to remove a lot of them at a time but I cant really figure out if it is the correct way to go about it

Comment: Simple way?  I would run the loop twice --  Once with `period='..'` -- THEN with `period='.'`  ..  It's the simplest solution and you're already set up to do it ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the bash extended glob `+(pattern)` to match one or more periods, combined with the `##` parameter expansion to remove the longest leading match:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Turn on extended globs
shopt -s extglob

name=...foo
printf "%s -> %s\n" "$name" "${name##+(.)}"
```

---

Or you can use a regular expression, combining looking for leading periods with capturing the rest of the name:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Note the quoted parameters to avoid many issues.
for i in "$@"; do
      if [[ "$i" =~ ^\.+(.*) ]]; then
            mv "$i" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
      else
            mv "$i" ".${i}"
      fi
 done
```

Comment: The second one works really well for my needs. May I just ask what BASH_REMATCH[1] does? This is the first time ive seen it

Comment: @honj-t `BASH_REMATCH` is an array that stores information from the last regular expression match. The first element is the full matching text, the rest are the capture groups (The bits in parenthesis; in this case everything after the leading periods is the first and only group, and thus the second element of the array).

Comment: More at https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-BASH_005fREMATCH

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try to read up more on this